# Click on different transparent PNG's. Which one is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, png

I am trying to create a map of a country, divided in different provinces. When my products are available in a certain provinces, these provinces will light up on the map. I then want people to be able to select one province and click on it.

I'm thinking of doing it like this:
1) I have a background of the complete country in dark colors
2) Every province has a separate transparent png in a light color
3) When my database detects a product is available, it will show the background image + the light color image of each province

The problem is: I want the light color image to be clickable, but the canvas of all the images will overlap. Is there any way  to accomplish this ? It should work in all major browsers, and preferably NOT with image maps. I would like to link the clickable area to the non-transparent part of the PNG image.

I hope this makes a bit sense, many thanks in advance.

Comment: How many different provinces are there?  Is it feasible to just have a different image for all the different possible selections?

Comment: how about setting proper z-index?

Comment: There are about 10 provinces, so it's quite impossible to create an image for every possible combination. But even that wouldn't solve my problem: if I highlight 3 provinces, I want to know which of these 3 the user clicks on.

Comment: @mkk: how does that help? I assume the problem is that the provinces aren't exact rectangles so whichever one is on top can have the problem that the corner of the rectangular image isn't actually part of the region... Effectively you need to pass through clicks on transparent parts of the image...

Comment: @Chris you are completely right, my bad. That's not the correct way to go.

Comment: Seems to me you want to make this very complex, just for the sake of not wanting to use an image map.  That makes no sense.  This is a classic case for a map.

Comment: Out of interest why are image maps out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to just create your `world` image, and another `hittest` image, where all provinces are a different color. When the user clicks somewhere, you can just get the color of the clicked pixel, and relate that back to the province. So your `hittest` image would, for example, have Texas as red, California as blue and New York as Green. When you click you just have to figure the color out, and there you have your state.

As for getting the pixel color under the mouse, canvas can do that. However thats not supported in < IE8, perhaps you can look into explorercanvas. Otherwise you could do it serverside, just do an AJAX request to your page with the (relative!)x/y on click, your backend can figure it out then.

Comment: A more widely supported way to get an x/y for the image would just being using `<input type="image">` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#input-control-types). when clicked it submits with an x and y co-ordinate of the click. Should be supported on all browsers since its been in the spec for ages and I'm sure (though I've not checked) that javascript libraries will let you capture the click and get the x/y and ajax it up if you want to.

Comment: Out of interest what is the recommended way to make your hittest image not actually the visible one? Do you just use visibility or does that prevent the click affecting it too?

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the tip. And, well if possible you could make it visible. It would be less loading for the client. On the flipside, if the artist would change the colors of the provinces on the map, your code could break.

Comment: @Cristy, beat you by 7 minutes ;)

Comment: @TJHeuvel: I guess you could use the least significant 2 bits of the RGB portions and use them to store an ID for which country that colour is so they will appear all the same colour (at a glance at least) but you'll be able to extract the information you want. I may be overthinking this though but I've always wanted to do soemthing like that ever since I saw http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Digital_steganography :)

Answer (score 0):

You can register click only on whole images, not colored parts of it. To have your map accurate you'll have to use canvas or flash.

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` tag is clickable by it's square size, doesn't matter if part of image is transparent. Even if you click on transparent part of image, the click event will occur.

To couter-act that, take a lok at **HTML IMAGE MAP** `<area>` HTML tag (google it) and optionally tell the browser what part of image do you want to apply some event.

Click will also propaginate to bottom elements at the same position. This means that `<body>` is always clicked, if you don't stop propagination with `e.stopPropagination();`

If you don't want image maps, you can place **invisible DIVs** on the top in the shape of the clickable area. But I'd probably go with image maps.

Comment: The OP stated `preferably NOT with image maps`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but either image maps or nothing. No alternative other than the one I wrote at the end.

Comment: The shape of the clickable area's are very irregular. I do have the shape in my transparent png's, so I was hoping there is some way to link the clickable area to the non-transparent channel in the png files.

Comment: You can have polygonial area. There exist programs that can assist you with the coordinates.

Comment: You can use slightly different colors for each region and then using javascript get the color of the clicked pixel then redirect to the region having that color :). Oh, and you can use Dreamweaver tpo quickly draw an image map if you want to..